# Imported user IDs and primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm designing a SQL table that should hold the client data.

The client data is exported from another system and already contains a `client_ID` that I need to integrate into my client table.

My question is: If I put an exported `client_ID` as a primary key and import the data, how should I auto increment the `client_ID` on consecutive table inserts by my system?

How should I eliminate the overlap of the client IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client_ID field is AUTO_INCREMENT, then you don't need to do anything specific, next time you insert into that table, Mysql will automatically use the next value of the greatest existing client_ID.

Comment: I think that is not correct since when he tried to insert a row with an id which already exists MySQL will throw an exception. In the past I had some trouble with that issue.

Comment: @JCalcines Of course MySQL won't allow you to insert two records with the same id, but as the author is asking "how should I **auto increment** the client_ID..." I'm assuming he doesn't intend to insert rows with predefined ids after the initial import of the client data.

Comment: You're wright but the column `clientId` is going to be imported from other table. So, In case he imported the value 1 for this field when he tried to insert the first row, MySQl will return value 1 too, and that will throw an exception.

Comment: So if he imported value 1 into that table, and then he tries to insert another row without specifying the `client_id`, MySQL will generate id 2, not 1.

Answer (score 2):

You could import all your data and then establish the next number of the autoincrement

```
ALTER TABLE CLIENT AUTO_INCREMENT = lastClientId;
```

Where you have to replace lastClientId for  the last id imported